# Why is std::unexpected() not called when I throw an exception in a function specified with an empty throw() specifier?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2013

My understanding of the throw() specifier is that any exception types not listed in the specifier will cause a call to std::unexpected(), when thrown from within a given function. 
So I expect the output of the following code to be "unexpected called", but instead I see "Caught an exception". I'm compiling this with VS2013 which doesn't implement `noexcept` which is why I'm using `throw()`.

```
#include <iostream>       
#include <exception>      

void testFunc() throw () {
    throw std::exception();
}

int main(void) {
    std::set_unexpected([](){
        std::cout << "unexpected called"; 
    });

    try {
        testFunc();
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Caught an exception"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why is std::unexpected not called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wfa0edys%28v=vs.120%29.aspx says that:

> Visual C++ departs from the ISO C++ Standard in its implementation of
>   exception specifications.
>
> [...]
>
> [...] if an exception is thrown out of a function marked `throw()`, the
>   Visual C++ compiler **will not call `unexpected`** [...].
>
> [...]
>
> Due to code
>   optimizations that might be performed by the C++ compiler (based on
>   the assumption that the function does not throw any C++ exceptions) if
>   a function does throw an exception, the program may not execute
>   correctly.

Additionally, in support of the above, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/awbt5tew.aspx says:

> The C++ Standard requires that `unexpected` is called when a function
>   throws an exception that is not on its throw list. The current
>   implementation does **not support** this.